# Handling multiple/frequent calls to UIView needsDisplayInRect efficiently

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I am working on an iPad application which has a custom drawn `UIView` which basically covers the whole screen. It is an audio application and it has VU meters which get update messages over ethernet about 30 times a second which then tell the UI to redraw the VU meters on the screen.

The problem I have is that there are 16 VU meters at various positions in the view and I end up calling `needsDisplayInRect` for each one 30 times a second. If I do all of the drawing in the `drawRect` function then it works, but it's pretty sluggish as the `CGRect` passed in to `drawRect` is almost the entire screen.

In the OSX version there is the `NSView` `getRectsBeingDrawn` function which gave me a route to significantly improve the redraw performance. However, as far as I'm aware there is no equivalent function in iOS.

I've tried storing the `CGRects` that I've called then only redrawing them in `drawRect`, but it turns out that iOS often decides to redraw areas between the `CGRects` that have had `needsDisplayInRect` called on them, so I end up with big white rectangles on areas that I've not requested a redraw for (although I do get the performance improvement I'm expecting). The problem here is that I can't see a way to get the rects that are actually being redrawn, just the rect passed into drawRect which is essentially a union of all of the rects being redrawn.

So, is there any other way to speed up very frequent redraws of small areas of a `UIView` that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is almost certainly to make a subview for each VU meter. Presumably you'd just have one `VUMeterView` class and make sixteen instances of it.